# PHP variables reference and memory usage

Tags: php, variables, memory-management, reference

According to [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php):

```
<?php
$a =& $b;
?>
// Note:
// $a and $b are completely equal here. $a is not pointing to $b or vice versa.
// $a and $b are pointing to the same place.
```

I assume that:

```
<?php
$x = "something";
$y = $x;
$z = $x;
```

should consume more memory than:

```
<?php
$x = "something";
$y =& $x;
$z =& $x;
```

because, if i understood it right, in the first case we 'duplicate' the value `something` and assign it to `$y` and `$z` having in the end 3 variables and 3 contents, while in the second case we have 3 variables `pointing` the same content.

So, with a code like:

```
$value = "put something here, like a long lorem ipsum";
for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++)
{
    ${"a$i"} =& $value;
}
echo memory_get_usage(true);
```

I expect to have a memory usage lower than:

```
$value = "put something here, like a long lorem ipsum";
for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++)
{
    ${"a$i"} = $value;
}
echo memory_get_usage(true);
```

But the memory usage is the same in both cases.

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PHP does not duplicate on assignment, but on write. See [Copy-on-Write in the PHP Language (Jan 18 2009; by Akihiko Tozawa, Michiaki Tatsubori, Tamiya Onodera and Yasuhiko Minamide; PDF file)](http://www.research.ibm.com/trl/people/mich/pub/200901_popl2009phpsem.pdf) for a scientific discussion of it, [Do not use PHP references (Jan 10, 2010; by Jan Schlüter)](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html) for some fun and my own take is [References to the Max](https://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/02/18/references-to-the-max/) with more references.

Answer (score 4):

PHP uses [copy-on-write](http://uk.php.net/debug_zval_dump) so it won't use more memory for the duplicated strings until you modify them.