# PHP $_POST, $_GET, or $_REQUEST

Tags: php, html, post, get, request

I have a functions file where I handle POST and GETS letting the user perform either a post or a get.  It's more like an API call.

Should I be doing it like this or would using $_REQUEST handle both a POST and a GET?

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "GET") {

    $function = $_GET['f'];
    $user_id  = $_GET['user_id'];
}
elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {

    $function = $_POST['f'];
    $user_id  = $_POST['user_id'];
}

$res = new stdClass();

if (isset($function)) {

    switch ($function) {    
         ....
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, `$_REQUEST` handles both `$_GET` and `$_POST`

Comment: I like the way you're doing it now. `$_REQUEST` also potentially has `$_COOKIE` values, depending on the ini variable [variables_order](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) which may vary from system to system.  Explicit is  better than ambiguous.

Comment: That's pretty much the point of having $_REQUEST.

Comment: Read the description of the documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: be careful of mixed parameters from different sources ie posting y to index.php?x=1 with z in a cookie and having request contain x, y and z

Comment: @Waygood You should check your input anyway. Requests can be forged no matter how the data is sent to your server. Explicitly using `$_GET` or `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST` doesn't make it any safer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The benefit that your current approach offers it that you can use the best method for each instance. There are some times when you would not want to GET since it just appends the data to the URL, exposing it to anyone who looks as well as exposing that "call" to anyone who knows how to use URLs for bad things.

If you are worried about catching calls that you not not be able to controll the request method, you could add the $_REQUEST as a last resort but I would suggest limiting what you use that for - example: just pulling data from the DB and not anything that modifies it.

Comment: The disadvantage is that he cannot mix $_REQUEST types (within the if statement of course)

Comment: People who know that, also know how to post things. That's not so hard either. It would be bad if your own page would pass sensitive information in the url, but on the receiving side it doesn't hurt to support it. It is easy for debugging purposes.

Comment: Another disadvangtage is duplicating code! how about this
`$vars = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "GET" ? $_GET : $_POST;`
`$vars['user_id']`

Comment: It would be `$user = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' ? $_GET['user_id'] : $_POST['user_id']);`

Comment: @RobertDeBoer no, I am assinging all values from `$_POST` or `$_GET` to be accessable within `$var` so that you don't need the if statement every time you want to get a variable

Comment: @RoryPicko92 Right, see that now `$var= ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' ? $_GET : $_POST);`

Comment: @RobertDeBoer the parenthesis only add readability benefits, they are both programatically the same and return the same results.

Comment: Learn something new every day

Comment: @RoryPicko92 would the assigment to `$var` cause a copy to occur (i.e. with added cpu/memmory expenses)? If so would this: `$vars = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "GET" ? &$_GET : &$_POST;` prevent the copy (i.e. by is using the [php reference operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)? )?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace PHP does not duplicate on assignment, but on write. Take a look at this SO Q&A for more details and links to articles http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993658/php-variables-reference-and-memory-usage

Answer (score 3):

If you want to allow both, you can just use `$_REQUEST`. It's much easier if you don't care whether the value was POSTed or -er- GETted. Note, though, that `$_REQUEST` may contain cookies as well, based on [settings in PHP.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php).

Comment: "request_order: Note that the default distribution php.ini files does not contain the 'C' for cookies, due to security concerns.", meaning $_REQUEST can contain any of the 3, depending on the server config.

Answer (score 1):

`$_REQUEST` *can* be both `$_POST` and `$_GET`, but it *can* also be `$_COOKIE` as well, depending on the [request_order](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order) or [variables_order](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) settings. Because it can also be neither of these depending on an ini setting, I wouldn't use it at all.

My recommendation is use `$_GET` and `$_POST` separately. They mean completely different things. You want to use a `$_POST` for an action, and a `$_GET` for fetching. If you want form filling based on `$_GET` you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'` to determine what is actually happening and toggle between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, `$_REQUEST` handles both `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins 'or would using $_REQUEST handle both a POST and a GET?'

Answer (score 0):

`$_REQUEST` is the most convenient way to handle the both type of request `($_GET & $_POST)`. So use the $_REQUEST :

[REQUEST METHOD IN PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)