# PHP Variable aliases (References?) - trying to reduce memory usage

Tags: php, memory, memory-management, reference

I read the answer to this question but it led to more questions: [PHP variables reference and memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993658/php-variables-reference-and-memory-usage)

In short, I have a project where I'm trying to loop through a multidimensional array to grab one value before continuing on with either the process or the loop. It'll be easier to explain in code:

```
// Demo variables
$this->content['alias1'] = ('object' => new someObject; 'info' => array('type' => 'abc'));
$this->content['alias2'] = ('object' => new someObject; 'info' => array('type' => 'def'));
$this->content['alias3'] = ('object' => new someObject; 'info' => array('type' => 'abc'));
```

... that's incredibly simplified, but it gets the point across.
I want to loop through that and find all of the 'types' that are 'abc' - what's the easiest way to do it? I had something like this

```
foreach($this->content as $alias => $data) {
    if ($data['info'] != 'abc') {
       break;
    }

    // Do actual "abc" things
}
```

But I'm trying to write all of this code as memory-conscientious as I can.  I feel as though there's probably a more efficient way to do this.

I was thinking that when the objects are loaded (this is essentially a config file), it would assign a reference to another variable, something like

```
$this->types->$type =& $this->content['alias1'];
```

for each. In the question referenced above, it said that PHP uses copy-on-write with references - if the reference is only read, never written, would this be an efficient way to be able to access the object? I was also thinking that maybe I could just store the array key name in the `$this->types->$type` array.

Answer (score 2):

Copy-on-write means that PHP will automatically create a reference for you, provided you don't write to the target variable. If you write, it will copy the original value, and modify the copy instead. Bottom line is: you don't need to manually assign by reference in this case, you can just use a regular assignment:

```
$this->types->$type = $this->content['alias1'];
```

As long as you're just reading from `$this->types->$type`, it will be pointing to the same value in memory as `$this->content['alias1']`.

Comment: Oh, now that's interesting. I didn't know that! Just to clarify, using `=&` and `=` would essentially be the same until the second is modified?

Comment: Not sure if they're technically the same, I believe I heard you even use *less* memory when you don't manually create a reference.

Comment: @JoshToth A good reference (haha) on this is http://php.net/features.gc.refcounting-basics

Comment: interesting. And the read will come in handy! (nice pun, too :P )

Answer (score 1):

**PHP does copy on write for most of variables you pass around as arguments.** Anyways, that's what my experiments led me to believe *(even if you can break this in special cases)*. So, if you just need to loop and you don't play with references and such... you'll be safe.

**But there's a way to check.** Using the following 2 functions:

- [**`memory_get_usage()^`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php)
- [**`memory_get_peak_usage()^`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php)

Use these two functions inside your code and check how your memory consumption changes as your code execution advances. **This way, no matter what funky things you do with PHP, you'll easily tell if PHP is still doing copy-on-write or has done the copy for you.**

Comment: Haha yeah I was thinking of checking memory usage... I'm just lazy and thought maybe someone who knew more than I would be able to enlighten me :P

Comment: @JoshToth In theory, as long as you just loop the arrays with no references, you're safe 99%. But if you are so *'memory-conscientious'* you have to get ready to get your hands dirty with memory usage tracking.

Comment: good point. It's just that I'm at work right now and I had the idea this morning in the shower and wanted to know right away :P I shouldn't have said lazy, I should have said impatient.